# Find unmatched column in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

[image][image]

I have 2 tables query-hive-2022 and ppdb-2022 i want to find for the userdid in  ppdb-2022 which did is not present in  query-hive-2022 table.

I am using this query to achieve this

```
SELECT * FROM CBAX.`ppdb-2022` as t1 inner join  CBAX.`query-hive-2022` as t2
on t1.userdid=t2.userdid 
where  t1.did is null ;
```

but it is not returning results.

Comment: Please do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of code or data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring pictures of data, this sounds like a job for *exists*

```
select *
from `ppdb-2022` p
where not exists (
  select * from `query-hive-2022` q
  where q.userdid = p.userdid
);
```